# Calculate the date yesterday in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-scripts

How can I calculate last day as a date in node jst?

I run the script include data of yesterday.
i wanna change it.the last day of month i have issue. for example
Date:1-4-2022
but the script include data of yesterday
we need the file name is :Example_March

how can i define it in this code

```
 const curMonth = new Date().toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" });

  let fileName = `example_${curMonth}.xlsx`;
  

  writeInFileAsync(html, fileName).then(() => {
    sendEmail(htmlForEmail, fileName);
```

)}

and save the sheet its the same issue.

```
const convertJsonToExcel = (table, fileName) => {
  var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(table, {
    sheet: `example_${new Date().getMonth() + 1}`,
    
  });

  XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName, { cellStyles: true });
};
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want the last day of the previous month or Today - 1 day?  These have different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the yesterday date in javascript, you can use this helper function:

```
function getYesterdayDate() {
  return new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24*60*60*1000);
}
```